# Sql joining tables and form as single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in combining result set of 2 database, help me by providing query

```
table 1:
id name email
1  name1  nam1@gmail.com
2  name2  nam2@gmail.com
3  name3  nam3@gmail.com


table 2:
id
2
```

Now, i have a query for first table

```
select * from table1 where email='nam3@gmail.com'
```

and query for second table

```
select * from table2
```

Now, i need result of

```
id name email 
3  name3  nam3@gmail.com(first query result)
2  name2  nam2@gmail.com(second query result)
```

Comment: so exactly how are these tables related? if `id=2` is the only thing in table #2, then why would `id=3` be returned from the query?

Comment: @MarcB If I have to guess, it would be because the `where email='nam3@gmail.com'` from the first query

Comment: Whats the contents of table1 and table2? And describe the wanted output,.

Comment: @jarlh I would understand if you'd like to see what have op tried to do, but both the contents of the tables and the output are right there on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table1 where email='nam3@gmail.com
union all   
select * from table1 where id in (select id from Table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE A.email='nam3@gmail.com'
OR t2.id = 2
```